# I cannot use import in Jasmine2 spec when using protractor 4.0.9 when using typescript 2.0

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

When I try to use typescript .ts spec and run them in protractor, I get:

```
[17:05:52] E/launcher - Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\inform-locate-E2E-tests\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:84:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Jasmine.loadSpecs (C:\Users\gwk736\Gitlab\inform-locate-E2E-tests\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:83:18)
```

[17:05:52] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

When I have .ts file and no import is present it's behaving ok. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

) Get the same error, using: Jasmine2, Protractor 4.0.11, typescript 2.0.3

And I don't know what seems to be the problem. But my workaround is:

in file: main-page.ts

```
module.exports = {
    setUrl: function(){
       browser.get("/");
    }
};
```

and in file you want to use the function setURL for example:

```
var mainPage = require('./main-page.ts');

describe('Test Main Page', function() {
it('should have a title', function() {
    mainPage.setUrl();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Titel meiner Seite');
    });
});
```

That's just my workaround - actually I didn't find out the real reason for the problem you described!